# Validar campo requerido en DropDownList ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validación

Estoy intentado validar un dropdownlist que sea obligatorio al momento de registrar pero no lo logro conseguir

En el modelo de la vista ya tengo definida la propiedad `[Required]`

**PriorityModel.cs**

```
public class Priority
    {

        public string PriorityId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PriorityName { get; set; }
        public int? PriorityTime { get; set; }
```

Estoy usando un `select` para hacer mi **dropdownlist**

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group" id="PriorityDiv">
                        <label for="ticketPriorityInput">Prioridad:</label>
                        <select required class="form-control form-control-user " id="ticketPriorityInput" name="prioridad" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Intente colocar la opción `required` al `select` pero no funciono

Controlador donde cargo el dropdownlist

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
        public  JsonResult LoadPriority()
        {
            var result = PriorityModel.GetPriorities();

            return Json(result.PriorityList);
        }
```

Esta es la funcion en js para cargar las prioridades dentro del dropwdownlist

**LoadData.js**

```
function loadPriority() {
    const url = document.getElementById("priority").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                const prioridad = document.getElementById("ticketPriorityInput");

                for (let idx in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                        const option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.innerHTML = data[idx].PriorityName;
                        option.value = data[idx].PriorityId;
                        prioridad.options.add(option);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Estas usando .Net Core o .Net Framework? Necesitas por requerimiento llenar el select-option con ajax? O lo pudieras llenar desde la primera llamada a tu controlador?

Comment: Estoy utilizando .Net Framework, y la que se adapte mas facil al codigo y al select que ya tengo hecho

Answer (score 0):

tienes diferentes opciones una de ellas es hacer uso de la propiedad `RequiredValidator`

para lo cual deberás emplear una estructura como la siguiente

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorReporte" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NombreSelect" ErrorMessage="Tipo de Reporte requerido" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="*" InitialValue="-- Seleccione --">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

otra opción es crear el evento SelectedIndexChanged y habilitar la propiedad de tu control autopostBack. Lo que haras desde el codebehind es indicar que si el valor de tu lista es seleccione, genere un mensaje de error, algo asi como lo siguiente:

```
protected void NombreSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
if (NombreSelect.SelectedIndex > 0)
}
else
{
CustomValidator error = new CustomValidator
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Por favor seleccion una opcion",
                    IsValid = false
                };
                Page.Validators.Add(error);
}
```

Comment: Lo intente con la primera opcion colocando el **<asp:RequiredFieldValidator** dentro del div pero aun no logro que sea requerido

Comment: tienes el autopostBack en true?

Comment: No amigo, revisa que en el controlador no tengo el **autopostBack**

Comment: son propiedades de tu control, habilitala

Comment: Lo declaro dentro de la propiedad **asp:RequiredFieldValidator** pero no lo lee

Comment: asp:RequiredFieldValidator es para WebForms, y me imagino estas trabajando en MVC.

Comment: Exacto estoy trabajando con MVC por esa razon no lee el **asp:RequiredFieldValidator**